# python - using backslash with subprocess.check_output

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am writing a script to connect to my wifi using Python in Ubuntu Operating System. The follwing is my code:

```
from subprocess import check_output
network = 'abcnetwork'
password = r'Pass|\|ew2017;'
output = check_output(
    ['nmcli d wifi connect {network} password {password}'.format(
        network=network, password=password)],
    shell=True
)
```

But I am getting the error because of `\`:

```
/bin/sh: 1: |ew2017: not found
`enter code here`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 626, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 708, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['nmcli d wifi connect abcnetwork password Pass|\\|ew2017;']' returned non-zero exit status 127
```

What is the mistake in my code. Kindly help.

Comment: Just add `"` to your variables, so shell wont treat backslash as newline escape. Something like `'nmcli d wifi connect "{network}" password "{password}"'.`

Comment: Thank you @YaroslavSurzhikov. Its working. Can you answer it so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `"` to your variables, so shell wont treat backslash as newline escape. Something like

```
'nmcli d wifi connect "{network}" password "{password}"'
```

In your example, you command equal to this:

```
nmcli d wifi connect abcnetwork password Pass|\
|ew2017;
```

If you copy-paste that into terminal - you will get exactly the same output as subprocess show ( except the python traceback ):

```
/bin/sh: 1: |ew2017: not found
```

Comment: This may work for this particular password, but will fail in general. (Specifically, consider a password that contains a `"`.)

Comment: @chepner Oh, yeah, my bad. I suppose creating shell variable and passing it with `env=` could do the trick too

Answer (score 4):

Pass the command as a list of words, not a single string (with `shell=False`, which is the default).

```
output = check_output(['nmcli', 'd', 'wifi', 'connect', network, 'password', password])
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `shell=True` to rely on the shell word splitting. Instead, pass a list of arguments to `check_output`:

```
output = check_output([
    'nmcli', 'd', 'wifi', 'connect', network, 'password', password
])
```

This way you also do not need to use extra quotes.

Using `shell=True` is advised against in the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments).